# Android Realm storing null instead of real values

Tags: android, realm

i'm conding an Android app and using Realm to persist data, but in just one case not attributes of my data are been saved, there's no migrations the schema is new, here's my code

```
public class ContractAttachments extends RealmObject {
@Required
private String nameOfFile;
private String pathOfFile;

public String getNameOfFile() {
    return nameOfFile;
}

public void setNameOfFile(String nameOfFile) {
    this.nameOfFile = nameOfFile;
}

public String getPathOfFile() {
    return pathOfFile;
}

public void setPathOfFile(String pathOfFile) {
    this.pathOfFile = pathOfFile;
}
```

}

```
realm.beginTransaction();
ContractAttachments attachment = new ContractAttachments();
attachment.setPathOfFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
attachment.setNameOfFile("nome");
realm.copyToRealm(attachment);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: maybe `attachment.setPathOfFile(file.getAbsolutePath());` is null? What's in the debugger (in the accessor methods)?

Comment: check https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging-android-studio-debugging maybe the problem is value has been saved, but the debugger shows `null`.

Comment: breender, you're the best, some other error on my application makes me believe that this 'null' values were the problem, thankyou!